# Filter results if not contained in another column

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

Is there an equivalent way to do the following SQL command with Django's QuerySet API?

```
select id, childid from mysite_nodetochild
where childid NOT IN (Select "Nodeid" from mysite_nodetochild)
```

I would prefer not to use raw sql if possible but I can't get a clean working version using Django's Queryset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
nodetochild.objects.exclude(childid=nodetochild.objects.values_list('Nodeid', flat=True)).only('id', 'childid')
```

This should evaluate to, more or less:

```
SELECT "mysite_nodetochild"."id", "mysite_nodetochild"."childid" FROM "mysite_nodetochild" WHERE NOT ("mysite_nodetochild"."childid" =  (SELECT U0."nodeid" FROM "mysite_nodetochild" U0))
```

Or, if you need the `IN` condition:

```
nodetochild.objects.exclude(childid__in=nodetochild.objects.values_list('Nodeid', flat=True)).only('id', 'childid')
```

Would evaluate to:

```
SELECT "mysite_nodetochild"."id", "mysite_nodetochild"."childid" FROM "mysite_nodetochild" WHERE NOT ("mysite_nodetochild"."childid" IN  (SELECT U0."nodeid" FROM "mysite_nodetochild" U0))
```